# For Husky pre-push hook, how can I make "echo" command to display information in VSCode Output?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, hook, husky, git-husky

I have 2 Husky hooks: `pre-commit` and `pre-push`. In both hooks, I use `echo` to print out progress information and call tasks such as build and test. While the `pre-commit` hook prints the output as expected (both the `echo` as well as the tasks output), nothing is printed when the `pre-push` hook is called. Why is that?

Comment: @starball sorry, it's typo and I corrected that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Does pre-push hook work at all? I had the same issue but it turned out that the hook wasn't triggered because I created `pre-push` file in the VS Code.
Removing the file and adding it in the terminal(`npx husky add .husky/pre-push "echo 'Husky started...'"`) fixed my issue